# How to set MaxNWts value in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to impute categorical data through the mice package.

```
{qualiD = mice(quali,1, seed=123)}
```

And I get the following error:

> {Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE,
>   softmax = TRUE,  :    too many (2184) weights}

I tried increasing the number of weights by including the MaxNWts param.

```
{qualiD = mice(quali,1, seed=123, MaxNWts = 3000)}
```

But then again i get this error:

> {Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE,
>   softmax = TRUE,  :    formal argument "MaxNWts" matched by multiple
>   actual arguments}

Comment: Looks like v2.3 changed something around here

"FIXED    multinom MaxNWts type fix in polyreg and polr #9"

https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/releases

Comment: The argument may have changed it's name to "nnet.MaxNWts".
https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/search?utf8=✓&q=MaxNWts&type

Answer (score 3):

Pass the argument using nnet.MaxNWts

```
qualiD = mice(quali,1, seed=123, nnet.MaxNWts = 3000)
```

This is described in the documentation of the mice imputation functions, e.g. mice.impute.polr