# Error of ' "MaxNWts" matched by multiple actual arguments'

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm receiving a matched arguments error when attempting to run MICE. I've tried increasing the maxits and maxnwts, but I'm still getting errors.

```
mice(df, m = 7, printFlag = FALSE, maxit = 350, seed = 123, MaxNWts = 50000)
```

> Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : 
>     formal argument "MaxNWts" matched by multiple actual arguments
>   Calls: mice ... sampler.univ -> do.call -> mice.impute.polyreg -> multinom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you added the `maxit` and `MaxNWts` arguments to `mice()`, you are getting a different error, aren't you?

As stated in its documentation, `mice()` actually calls other functions when imputing the variables. `mice.impute.polyreg()`, which is part of the error message, is the default imputation function for categorical variables. If you read the documentation for `mice.impute.polyreg()`, you will see that its argument is called `nnet.MaxNWts`, not `MaxNWts`. `mice.impute.polyreg()` passes the value of `nnet.MaxNWts` to the `MaxNWts` argument of `nnet::multinom()`.

If you provide an `MaxNWts` argument for `mice.impute.polyreg()`, it will pass **two** `MaxNWts` to `nnet::multinom()`: one with the default value of `nnet.MaxNWts`, and another (via the ...) with the value you supplied. The error message itself seems to originate from `match.call()`, inside `nnet::multinom()`.

You could (re)produce this error by simply typing `mean(x = 1, x = 2)`.

If you replace `MaxNWts` with `nnet.MaxNWts` in your call, you should stop receiving this error message.

Please notice that you didn't actually ask your question, just communicated you are (still) getting an error message. Let me know if my answer is not what you needed.

Due credit: This answer is an expanded version of [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665451/4825192), by Gordon Li. I myself found that answer when I got the same error message as you!